# Apply MarkerOptions to a Kmllayer?

Tags: kml

I have a KmlLayer loading successfully, though the pins are getting cut off due to canvas tiles, so it was suggested to turn "optimized: false" to the MarkerOptions.

So far everything I'm reading is showing how to set MarkerOptions when you're creating a new marker object, but I don't know how to apply MarkerOptions to the markers generated by the KML file.

How would I be able to set the MarkerOption of "optimized: false" to the code below? Or can I do this?

```
var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 3,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.157523,-100.25987),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);

georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('[KML FILE]', {preserveViewport:true});

georssLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you are trying to fix including some KML that will reproduce it.  There is no `MarkerOptions` for [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerOptions), my suspicion is your problem is with the styles in your KML interacting with the Google Maps Javascript API v3/Google Maps KML rendering engine.

Comment: Related issue on the issue tracker: [Issue 10662: Bug: KML places renderer broken](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10662)

Comment: Example in the documentation that exhibits a similar (?) issue: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features

Comment: The change has been rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been on Google's end. We were also experiencing this issue and it seems to have been resolved about an hour ago. Google will likely update this bug report:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10662